# Android "font asset not found" error

Tags: android, android-assets

I am developing for Android version 22.

I am getting the runtime exception "Font asset not found"

Here is the code:

```
Typeface customFont =    Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/norwester.otf");
```

And here is my file structure:

[image: First part of file structure]

[image: Second part of file stucture]

[image: 3rd part of file structure]

I am guessing that my file structure is wrong because the "assets" folder does not show up in "Android" mode and only shows up in "Project Mode".

What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Assets folder should be under root directory of main folder which inner folder of src.

For Reference Please find attached images of folder structure.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I am guessing that my file structure is wrong because the "assets" folder does not show up in "Android" mode and only shows up in "Project Mode"

According to your screenshots, you do not have an "assets" folder. You have a `res/assets.fonts/` folder. It has the wrong name (`assets.fonts`, not `assets`) and is in the wrong location (a child of `res/`).

Step #1: In your project tree, right-click over `main`.

Step #2: Choose New > Directory from the context menu that appears when you right-clicked.

Step #3: In the resulting dialog, type `assets`, then click OK. You will now have an `assets/` directory under `main`.

Step #4: In your project tree, right-click over your newly-created `assets` directory.

Step #5: Choose New > Directory from the context menu that appears when you right-clicked.

Step #6: In the resulting dialog, type 'fonts', then click OK. You will now have an `assets/fonts/` directory under main.

Step #7: Drag your font file from its current location to move it into `assets/fonts/`.

Step #8: Delete the `res/assets.fonts/` directory, which is now empty.

Comment: This did not work because when I tried to create an assets directory it said that I already had one. However what did seem to work was deleting the fonts directory inside assets then moving assets into main.

Answer (score 1):

> I am guessing that my file structure is wrong because the "assets" folder does not show up in "Android" mode and only shows up in "Project Mode".

Your `assets` is empty you can't see it in "Android mode". Change mode to "Project" and add your font to `assets` folder.

Right location of `assets` folder:

```
root-module
|--.idea
|--app
|----build
|----src
|------main
|--------assets
|----------norwester.otf
|--------java
|----------source code here
|--------res
|------AndroidManifest.xml
|----build.gradle
```

To create `assets` folder Right click on app->New->Folder->Assets Folder like below image.

[image: Create assets folder]

Answer (score 0):

The assets folder must be in the main folder, not in resources folder.
Also there is assets.fonts in your project which I guess is not the correct format. You can create the assets in the main directory, then right click -> New -> Directory and give its name as fonts

Hope this helps.