# Rendering error Android studio 3

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I've added new font "Roboto Light" in Android Studio 3 and it looks fine during runtime.

However, Android Studio shows rendering error all the time.

Render problem
Asset not found: @font/roboto_light

Here's screenshot with added font and error itself
http://take.ms/gFWhW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android "font asset not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224002/android-font-asset-not-found-error)

Comment: have you found a solution for this? i am facing this issue as well. 
this is not a duplicate as far as i know. this is related to the latest android studio version which supports 3rd party fonts.

Comment: No, I haven't found solution yet. However it seems problem is gone if you put font as "downloadable" instead of putting directly into the project.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to check if directory font is setup as a font resource directory. I had same problem and solved by creating a proper font resource directory and putting the font file inside.

Also, spaces are not allowed in the name of files, images and so on.

Hope it helps :)